# MySQL query has no results, has results a minute later, records seem unchanged

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

This might be a silly question, but it's a headbreaker for me.

1. I have a MySQL query which returns no results.
2. A few minutes later the same query returns the results I'd expect as result for the first query already.
3. The data in the table seems unchanged.

The query is

```
SELECT `id`, `currency_code`, `country_code`,`timestamp`
FROM `table`
WHERE `first_reference` = 'xxxxx'
AND `second_reference` = 'yyyy'
AND `result` = 'zzzzz'
LIMIT 1;
```

It's an InnoDB type, with a latin1_swedish_ci collation. Both queries are triggered by a cronjob. Let me know if more or other information is needed.

I was thinking about locked tables, but that shouldn't prevent reading, correct? Any clues, ideas or lightbulbs out there?

Comment: Can you please show us your query so anyone over get some idea what problem you have been facing off.

Comment: Are you certain that the table is not being altered?  Are there audit columns in the table that show when each row was inserted or last updated?

Comment: Yes there are last_update and created_on columns, there has been no update in the record since it's been created.

Comment: See my answer, should I just delete this question, or let it be with this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this seemed impossible and it actually was.

There were 2 crons running at the same time, one altering data that changed the records in 1 table and therefore changed the query which was executed.

Apologies for consuming your time here!